# equality by value and equality by refernce with linked list

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

it seems very difficult to get a proper source of information about Squeak. 
I have a few basic questions about it:

1. does '='   check for equality by refrence?
2. does '==' check for equality of values?
3. collection - linked list - if I do something like:

   ```
   list := LinkedList new.

   element := list first.
   ```

does it mean that element and 'list first' are both references to the same place in memory (the first place in thr linked list?)

4. why do I need to override the operator = for linked list? and how do I do it?

Comment: You probably mean list := LinkedList new.

Comment: yes.... you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `==` is equality by reference. In *Object* `=` is defined as

```
= anObject

   ^ self == anObject
```

But other classes usually override it. For example in *Character* `=` is defined as

```
= aCharacter 

   ^ self == aCharacter or:[
      aCharacter isCharacter and: [
         self asciiValue = aCharacter asciiValue]]
```

You can get all implementors of `=` by executing `#= implementors`.

In your case `element` and `list first` are referencing the same object. This is because `first` is implemented as

```
first
   ^ self at: 1
```

And `at` returns the element on position 1. But if `first` would be implemented as

```
first
   ^ (self at: 1) copy
```

then it would return a copy of an element (or if you use `element := list first copy`) and then they will return `false` when compared with `==`, but if `=` is implemented in a smart way it should return `true` in most cases.

Also be sure that you want to use *LinkedList* because in [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) which is a fork of [squeak](/questions/tagged/squeak) it is used mostly for process scheduling and I think that there was a discussion that *LinkedList* is more of a utility collection. The most used collection with random access features is `OrderedCollection`